# checking the checkbox on one page when click on button on another page WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am in deep problem since 1 week. Actually, I have one button in `MainWindow` page say `Button1` and one checkbox in Usercontrol page say `CheckBox1`. So the case is, when I click on `Button1` then the `CheckBox1` should show as Checked but nothing happening like this. I have Button1_Click method in MainWindow page where I invoked the `CheckBox1.IsChecked = true` by calling the instance of the UserControl class like

```
UserControl UC = new UserControl();  

UC.CheckBox1.IsChecked =true;
```

I am posting a demo code for more clarification: This is the waay I want to do

My MainWindow.Xaml Page:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfApplicationDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplicationDemo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Button x:Name="btnCheck" Width="110" Height="25" Margin="16,10,165,36" FontWeight="Medium" Click="btnCheck_Click" />
        <local:MyUserControlDemo x:Name="MyUserControlDemo" Visibility="Visible" Margin="-54,-49,56,49" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWindow.Xaml.cs page

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyUserControlDemo us = new MyUserControlDemo();
            us.chkCheckbox_CheckedChanged(null, null);
        }
    }
```

My UserControl.Xaml page

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWpfApplicationDemo.MyUserControlDemo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

        <CheckBox x:Name="chkCheckbox" Margin="45,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Cursor="Hand" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="chkCheckbox_CheckedChanged"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My UserControl.Xaml.cs Page

```
public partial class MyUserControlDemo : UserControl
    {
        static int count;
        public MyUserControlDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void chkCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            chkCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
        }

      }
```

but after getting the true value the checkbox is not checked and I want to get this done as soon as possible because my project will be delivered after resolving this issue.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the user control added on the window ? Can you be more specific by posting more code ?

Comment: Yes..I added the user control on the window

Comment: Please post more code for clarification. Posted code is not enough

Comment: Your question, and comments on suggested answers are not sufficient information to understand what you actually want.  Please provide more code/better explanation of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your checkbox and your usercontrol are in the same window just go to the parent of user control that is grid (probably), then go to the parent of grid that is MainWindow(probably) and set chkCheckbox.IsChecked = true;

example:

```
public void chkCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = this.Parent as Grid;
       if(grid != null)
       {
           var mainWindow = grid.Parent as MainWindow;
           if(mainWindow != null)
           {
               mainWindow.chkCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
           }
       }     
    }
```

UPD:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="Main"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 Tag="{Binding ElementName=Main}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="IsChecked?" x:Name="chkBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>



private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tag = Tag as MainWindow;
            if (tag != null)
            {
                tag.chkBox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
```

**UPD2:**
You don't need to create Instance of UserControl in button click event, cuz you've already one in XAML, so you need to use it:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyUserControlDemo.chkCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

**UPD3**
[image]

Here's MainWindow XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="Main"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:UserControl1 Tag="{Binding ElementName=Main}"/>
        <local:UserControl2 Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding ElementName=Main}" x:Name="Control2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UserControl1:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD3E424" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF189724" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Button Width="200" Height="50" Content="CLICK ME" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tag = Tag as MainWindow;
            if (tag != null)
            {
                tag.Control2.checkBox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl2**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF000CFF" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF03FF26" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CHECK ME" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I am getting the grid value null. also getting the red error on mainWindow.chkCheckbox

Comment: Then just Bind your window to tag on userControl. See example in answer.

Comment: @Ammy check answer

Comment: No, I dont want to Use checkbox control on the mainwindow page..My requirement is different..anyhow i want to use checkbox on user control page..

Comment: @ammy check answer update, don't create MyUserControlDemo in click event, user name of MyUserControlDemo in XAML!!

Comment: But still I have one concern. If we have button on one Usercontrol and checkbox on another usercontrol then will this solution work?

Comment: Then you need bridge between controls, eg MainWindow at Tag property of each other

Comment: @ammy chek answer

Comment: But why I am getting null value in tag variable?

Comment: May be I am not using ElementName properly. What to use element name in Binindg the value in Tag. Please help me as I am new to wpf